# Use function-returned server control in mark-up

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET 4.0, is it possible to have a function that returns a server control, and be able to call that function from inline code placing the server-side control in the rendered HTML?

*Note: The following is VB.NET, but could easily be C#, etc*

For instance, say I have a function...

```
Public Function GetImageButton(ByVal id As String) As ImageButton
  Dim btn As New ImageButton
  btn.ID = id
  AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click
  Return btn
End Function
```

What I would like to have in the mark-up is something like the following...

```
<div><%=GetImageButton("btn1")%></div>
```

This would position the server-control in that specific location in the HTML, but remain as a standard ASP.NET control, with event handling, etc.

However, the above will obviously result in the following being rendered as text...

```
<div>System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton</div>
```

My assumption is that it is not possible and it will be necessary to have something like a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control, which is populated through the code-behind.

---

**Update**

I have a temporary solution to the problem which I have provided as an answer.

I would still be very interested to hear any other suggestions/solutions

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I have the following temporary solution...

As per my assumption I am using a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` and passing it through to the function (now turned into a sub)...

```
Public Sub GetImageButton(ByVal plh as PlaceHolder, ByVal id As String)
  Dim btn As New ImageButton
  btn.ID = id
  ...
  plh.Controls.Add(btn)
End Sub
```

And then calling it using...

```
<%GetImageButton(plh1, "btn1")%>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="plh1" />
```

**Note** the order is important - the `Sub` call must be before the `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control, otherwise it doesn't work. I assume this is because the placeholder renders before the call to the `Sub` is made.

Comment: Does this really not output the `.ToString()` text of the control before the placeholder? Even in the source, if it's not being displayed in the browser? I'm kind of surprised it works, but if it does, then great :)

Comment: @Rob - if it was a function, and you used `<%= %>` then yes, it would

Comment: Ack - although you've made me notice a typo when I copied the function from the question and turned it into a `Sub`.  It shouldn't have the return type as that is obviously invalid syntax

Comment: Ah, my bad - I mentally equated the sub to a function (haven't used VB in a very long time). Makes sense, then.

Comment: @Rob - I envy you - unfortunately I'm working with legacy code that is simply too vast to convert to C#